# Disable 3D touch for UIButton in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, 3dtouch, peek-pop

I have a `UITableView` with customized `UITableViewCells`. In the cells I have a `UIButton` which I don't want to be trigged by the 3D touch event for the cell.

I want it to work in a similar manner as in **Apples messages app**, if you take a look there it works in the way that if you press the **thumbnail** for the message **sender image** (or initials) you get a different peek & pop from when you press the whole cell. Only difference is that ***I want to completely ignore the peek & pop for my button***. Anyone out there that knows a good solution to this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding a `UIButton` that covered the whole `UITableViewCell` and then for the `UIButton` I did not want to be triggered I created a separate `UIView` with clear background that I laid on top of the 3D touch triggered `UIButton`.

This creates a 3D touch animation for the whole `UITableViewCell` which looks awesomely beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `UIView` and use a `UITapGestureRecognizer` with a custom force touch gesture recognizer like [this `DeepPressGestureRecognizer`](https://github.com/FlexMonkey/DeepPressGestureRecognizer). Set up the gesture recognizers in a way that the `DeepPressGestureRecognizer` prevents the `UITapGestureRecognizer` from recognizing.

Comment: I do not think this will look very nice in the 3D touch animation. You will have to layout the button outside from the view and when you force touch the view only the view will get animated.